# How to convert timeStamp value wrapped in an optional into a double?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a function which fetches images from firebase based on some preliminary info, at the same tree level as the images is a time stamp value (for each image). I have been unable to get the value, only being able to get to `Optional(123131.432432)` which is not what I need of course.

**Below is the function:**

```
    func fetchAllPostImages() {
    print("fetchAllPostImages function")
    self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).child("Images").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        var snapshotUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageUrl")
        var timeStampData = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp").value

        print("fhdsjaklhfkjdsfksahdjksfjlashfkljdhs")
        print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageUrl"))
        print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp").value, "timestamp123")
        print(snapshotUrl.value as? [String: String], "value")

            if let urlValue = snapshotUrl.value {
                print("jkdhsjbbvcbcbcbccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
                let snapShotValue = [ "ImageUrl" : urlValue]
                let timeStampVal = ["timeStamp" : timeStampData]

                print(timeStampVal, "dsfaf")
                for (_, value) in snapShotValue {

                    if let imageURL = URL(string: value as! String) {
                        print(imageURL, "image url here")
                        do {
                            let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                            var timeStamp = 0.0
                            self.arrayOfImgObj.append(Media(image: image!, timeStamp: timeStamp))
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            print(self.arrayOfImgObj.count, "array.count")
                        } catch {
                            print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    })
}
```

So I was able to do the following and this seems to work however in the tableView I see teh same Optional(5421432.43214) as before. Even though when I print it it comes out as teh double value I needed.

```
for (value, timeValue) in zip(snapShotValue.values, timeStampVal) {
    if let imageURL = URL(string: value as! String) {
        print(imageURL, "image url here")
        do {
            let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
            var timeStampValue = timeValue as! Double
            print(timeStampValue, "fgsdfg")
            let timeStamp: Double = timeStampValue
            self.arrayOfImgObj.append(Media(image: image!, timeStamp: timeStamp))
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(self.arrayOfImgObj.count, "array.count")
        } catch {
            print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
        }
    }
}
```

**How to convert timeStamp value wrapped in an optional into a double?**

Comment: It's an optional. Unwrap it properly just like you are unwrapping other optionals in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy check update

Comment: 564030781.136256 fgsdfg
is what I get when i print teh value and yet i get teh optional thing in the tableView

Comment: You have another optional somewhere. Debug your code. Find where it is coming from. Then unwrap. BTW - using `as!` is a bad idea. It will crash if it's nil.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your firebase data in your question? Your timestamp and my timestamp might be two different things. Also, in the future, please reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue. There's a lot of junk code there which just makes it harder to read. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, *let snapShotValue = [ "ImageUrl" : urlValue]* looks like snapShotValue is a single URL, but then you iterate over it which is odd. *for (_, value) in snapShotValue*. The code is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the easiest way to do this to add an `Int` to where you call the `arrayOfImg[indexPath.row].timeStamp`. So it should look like this:

```
let timeStamp = "\(Int(arrayOfImg[indexPath.row].timeStamp))"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
let timeStamp: Double = timeStampValue
```

with

```
guard let timeStamp = timeStampValue as Double else { return }
```

This will safely unwrap your optional as well as cast the value as a Double.